# Galera - why can't I use port 4567 for replication?

Tags: mariadb, ubuntu, galera

I have two `Galera` clusters in two different datacenters.

I want to replicate cluster `c1`(using `c1-1` node as replication master) to cluster `c2` (using `c2-1` node as replication slave). Everything works well if I use port `3306` on `c2-1`for `MASTER_PORT` instead of the default port for replication `4567`.

If I switch from port `3306` to `4567` for `MASTER_PORT` I get this error when I run `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G` on `c2-1`:

```
Last_IO_Errno: 2013
Last_IO_Error: error connecting to master 'repl@x.x.x.x:4567' - retry-time: 60  maximum-retries: 86400  message: Lost connection to server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0 "Internal error/check (Not system error)"
```

This is what I get when I run `lsof -i:3306` on `c1-1`:

```
root@c1-1:~# lsof -i:3306
COMMAND   PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
mariadbd 1402 mysql   31u  IPv4  25689      0t0  TCP *:mysql (LISTEN)
```

And this is what i get when i run `lsof -i:4567` on `c1-1` (same node):

```
root@c1-1:~# lsof -i:4567
COMMAND   PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
mariadbd 1402 mysql    8u  IPv4  25683      0t0  TCP *:4567 (LISTEN)
```

Also I allowed all traffic (using `ufw`) on all those ports.

If I run `netcat x.x.x.x 3306` (`x.x.x.x` being `c1-1`'s ip) on `c2-1` I get this:

```
root@c2-1:~# netcat x.x.x.x 3306
q
5.5.5-10.5.9-MariaDB-1:10.5.9+maria~focal-log,)XbbFt8Z��-��:Srf(
```

And if I run `netcat x.x.x.x 4567` (`x.x.x.x` being `c1-1`'s ip) on `c2-1 I get this:

```
root@c2-1:~# netcat x.x.x.x 4567
$�-��\�цI�-Vk8�$
```

Why can't I use port `4567`? Is it not using the right socket? If so what can be done?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`4567` is the default Galera Replication Port for replication between nodes within a Galera cluster. That is not what you want to use here - you are doing primary-secondary replication (master-slave).

`3306` is the default TCP/IP port you want to use for primary-secondary (master-slave) replication.

Comment: Oh, that was...easy! Thank you so much! :D Now I have another question regarding circular replication #-o Should I post a new question?

Comment: Yes, new question, just remember to upvote or mark this as the correct answer first :)